# How add asmx class to project in Android Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, android-studio, asmx

I want to add a soap_base web service to the Android project in an Android Studio for connecting to SQL Server.

In the Xamarin IDE that is simple:

Right-click in the project, select a service reference, put in a URL, and download a class file from the server, but in the Android Studio, I can not find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add EasyWSDl plugin in android Studio
2. create a package in main/java
3. right-click on package and select EseayWSDL-add web service
4. put asmx url